# Video Editor for Windows?

Tags: windows, video-editing

I'm looking for an Advanced Video Editor **(No Movie Makers)** for Windows, with the below features:

- Video Trimmer: Trim videos to remove unwanted parts
- Video Reverse: Reverse video to make magic.
- Video Joiner: Merge multiple video clips into one video. can add music as well.
- Video & Audio Mixer: Add music to videos. Adjust video and music volumes.
- Animated GIF: Convert videos to animated GIF
- Video Transcoder: Convert videos to other formats, change the resolution to make your videos smaller. Supports conversion to GIF, 3GP, AVI, FLV, MP4, MPG, MOV, WMV and VOB formats.
- Slideshow Maker: Make slideshow from images, add fading effect and music.
- Frame Grabber: Extract video frame images at any moment of the video.
- Video Toolbox: Enhance video. Adjust brightness, contrast, saturation. Change audio volume
- Video Rotate: Rotate videos (Quick Rotation without encoding or True Rotation with encoding)
- Delete middle parts: Remove unwanted parts in the middle of videos.
- Add text, emojis, pictures to videos
- Convert video files to MP3 audio files
- Apply video effects like slow motion, sepia, vignette, vintage
- Split video files into two separate video clips

Answer (score 5):

[Blender](https://www.blender.org/) is a free and open-source 3D editing and includes a fully featured video editor.

Note: Blender doesn't have the best learning curve, and might be a little **difficult** to use in the beginning, but it has a lot of tutorials and if you are stuck at something small, it is pretty easy to find tutorials for your problem.

To use Blender as a video editor, install and open Blender, *press the plus sign* at the top, and select "*Video editing workspace*":
[image: set up blender as Video editing software]

And then drag and drop your video onto the video timeline

Some of the things you asked for:

- Video **trimmer**, **splitting**: [Cut strips](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/video_editing/sequencer/strips/introduction.html)
- Video **reverse**: [Play strip backward](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28943/video-sequence-editor-how-to-render-video-with-reversed-picture-order)
- Video **join**: Add 2 strips to the same timeline
- Video and audio **mixer**: Add audio strips by dragging audio files onto the timeline, and play them at the same time as your video strips
- Animated **GIF**: I would recommend exporting as a video and use an online mp4 to GIF converter
- **Frame grabber**: Using [blender freeze frames](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42056/how-do-i-create-a-freeze-frame-effect-with-video-editing) or [VLC snapshot](https://www.vlchelp.com/take-picture-snapshot-video/)
- Video **toolbox**, Video **Rotate**, video **effects**: **All** the listed functions are available. See [here](http://builder.openhmd.net/blender-hmd-viewport-temp/editors/vse/sequencer/strips/effects/index.html) for a list

With video **transcoding** and **converting** (to mp3), I would recommend using VLC, as this is much simpler. [See here](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/convert-video-using-vlc)

**Slideshow** maker: Making a slideshow would be a little tedious in Blender. If you want to drag and drop images and generate a whole slideshow, you would be better off using something else, like Adobe Spark (I haven't tried this).

Answer (score 3):

[DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/) is a free fully fledged video editor that does most of the things on your list apart from transcoding and GIFs. Additionally, using it as a slideshow maker would be tedious and not worth it. But every other dot point is well met.

It can be more demanding on your system then simplistic editors like "Movie Maker" and won't be usable on low-end machines. Ensure your system has a dedicated graphics card before even attempting to use it.

Comment: What is the minimum configuration for using DaVinci Resolve?